# Paypal IPN status "autochange"?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

i have a question about Paypal IPN (or other methods) to buy in a webpage.

Actually I use the IPN "background" method setting a form like this:

```
<form id="TPVFORM" name='formTpv' method='post' action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'>

<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>
<input type='hidden' name='business' value='xxxxxx@gmail.com'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='MORE THINGS'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='99.00'>
<input type='hidden' name='amount' value='23.00'>
<input type='hidden' name='page_style' value='paypal'>
<input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://www.xxxx.com/web/payOrder'>
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://www.xxxx.com/web/payFail'>
<input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2'>
<input type='hidden' name='no_note' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='EUR'>
<input type='hidden' name='cn' value='PP-BuyNowBF'>
<input type='hidden' name='custom' value=''>

<input type='hidden' name='lc' value='es'>
<input type='hidden' name='country' value='ES'>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And configure in my Paypal account the address of the IPN check .PHP file.
OK, to this point, all work correctly, but one question break me: Paypal have more "payment" status, "completed", "pending", "in revision".

If the pay status its "completed", I verify the other params, and SAVE the order in my DB, but if the status is, for example "pending", i DONT SAVE the order, if Paypal send a notificacion via IPN when the status is "pending", and "later" send other when the status is "completed" I no have problem, but if ONLY send the first status "pending" or "whaiting" or other think, ¿how i can check the payment status? ¿Paypal send one IPN call to my script when the status change?

Im lost..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YES**. Paypal will make a call to your IPN script when the payment is Completed, even if at the initial time of purchase, it is Pending or similar.

[Question asked in the PayPal Developer Network](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/ipn/pdt/does-ipn-send-completed-payment-status-after-pending-payment-status)

Comment: Thanks! this link clarify me all :)